# How to add new values to ComboBox after pressing the ENTER key?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'll be glad if you can assist me. I'm a newbie in WPF.

I've encountered a problem regarding ComboBox. I'm retrieving data of jobs from a MySql server using Ado.Net Entity Framework 5. My ComboBox needs to show the IDs of those jobs and it needs to be editable in order to add new IDs. The problem is once I input a new ID which is not exist in the combobox and press ENTER, nothing happens. I need that after pressing ENTER the new value will be added to the binding list of the ComboBox. I was told to use LOSTFOCUS (because PropertyChange will invoke for every key stroke and each key stroke will be considered as a new value in the combobox list) but nothing happens. I was told also that it's related to Behaviors and Commands. Since I'm a newbie I find difficulties. 
Can you please show me a solution example for this issue ? :)

## Job.cs

```
public class Job {
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="JobIdComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="JobID" ItemsSource="{Binding JobsList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem ="{Binding JobSelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Margin="360,37,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" FontSize="18" IsReadOnly="False" IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Path=JobNewItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace JobsApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

    }

}
```

## MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        JobsDbEntities jobsDbEntitiesInstance = new JobsDbEntities();


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            FillJobs();
        }

        private void FillJobs()
        {
            var q = (from Jobs in jobsDbEntitiesInstance.certificateheader
                     select Jobs).ToList();

            JobsList = q;


        }


        private List<Job> _jobsList;

        public List<Job> JobsList
        {
            get { return _jobsList; }
            set
            {
                _jobsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Job _jobSelectedItem;

        public Job JobSelectedItem
        {
            get { return _jobSelectedItem; }

            set
            {
                _jobSelectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }   




        private string _jobNewItem;

        public string JobNewItem
        {

            get { return _jobNewItem; }

            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _jobNewItem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();

                    var jobNewElement = new Job {JobID = _jobNewItem};

                    _jobsList.Add(jobNewElement);
                    JobSelectedItem = jobNewElement;

                }

            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there. Change UpdateSourceTrigger from LostFocus to PropertyChanged.

```
Text="{Binding Path=JobNewItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Hi. The problem is once I do so, the update is caused for every key stroke that is pressed. This situation causes for performance issues and also I need to add a data structure in order to keep every key until ENTER is pressed. Someone has told me that it can be solved by using Behaviors but I don't know how to implement it. Can you help me? :)